# How do I push out Environment Variable without reboot of workstations

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to push system system environment variables out to multiple workstations at once but I notice that the environment variables are not effective immediately on the workstation and it needs to be reboot. Is there a way to push out the variables and have it be effective immediately?

```
Invoke-Command ($Computers){
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('QSMULTICAST', 'TRUE', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('QSMULTICAST_IPADDRESS', '192.6.100.1', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('QSMULTICAST_TTL', '12', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
}
```